# Difficulty with a lemma needed to prove $A_n$ is a simple group for $n>4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

The theorem is:

> For $n \geq 5$, every normal subgroup $N$ of $A_n$ contains a $3$-
>   cycle.

The proof starts like this:

Let $\sigma$ be an arbitrary element in a normal subgroup $N$. There are several possible cycle structures for $\sigma$:

- $\sigma$ is a $3$-cycle.
- $\sigma$ is the product of disjoint cycles, $\sigma = \tau(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_r) \in N$, where $r > 3$.
- $\sigma$ is the product of disjoint cycles, $\sigma = \tau(a_1 a_2 a_3)(a_4 a_5 a_6)$.
- $\sigma = \tau(a_1a_2a_3)$, where $\tau$ is the product of disjoint $2$-cycles.
- $\sigma = \tau(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)$, where $\tau$ is the product of an even number of disjoint $2$-cycles.

I don't understand why $\sigma$ must be one of the forms. Is is possible they are just saying that $A_n$ must contain at least one of these and not that every element is one of these? If anyone could explain what I am missing that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worded ... not optimally, I agree. But, they are saying all even permutations fall into one of those 5 categories:

1. $\sigma$ is a $3$-cycle.
2. $\sigma$ is the product of disjoint cycles, $\sigma = \tau(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_r) \in N$, where $r > 3$.
3. $\sigma$ is the product of disjoint cycles, $\sigma = \tau(a_1 a_2 a_3)(a_4 a_5 a_6)$.
4. $\sigma = \tau(a_1a_2a_3)$, where $\tau$ is the product of disjoint $2$-cycles.
5. $\sigma = \tau(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)$, where $\tau$ is the product of an even number of disjoint $2$-cycles.

It's really a classification based on the number of $2$- and $3$-cycles the permutation has.

Does the permutation have only $2$- or $3$-cycles, and no longer cycles?

- If yes:

  - A single $3$-cycle, and nothing else? Case 1.
  - At least two $3$-cycles? Case 3.
  - A single $3$-cycle, and the rest $2$-cycles? Case 4.
  - No $3$-cycles, and only $2$-cycles?
- If no, the permutation has at least one cycle of length $\ell \geq 4$: Case 2.

Based on that consideration, I think a more revealing description for each case (using the original numbering) might be:

1. *A single $3$-cycle*
2. *Contains a "long" cycle, of length at least $4$*
3. *At least two $3$-cycles, potentially with $2$-cycles*
4. *Has a single $3$-cycle, and the rest $2$-cycles, with no larger cycles*
5. *An even number of $2$-cycles, and nothing else*

I've stared at this far too long and changed my mind several times, so I'll leave it up to you to check that these really partition the possibilities with respect to $2$- and $3$-cycles. But that should, at least, give you the idea of the classification that's being used.

Comment: I see. It is important here that cycles can't be broken down into disjoint smaller cycles. The cycles would have to have elements in common. In particular you can't break a 3-cycle down into disjoint 2-cycles.

Comment: Indeed, I'm assuming we were working with the cycle structure of $\sigma$, that it's been broken down into disjoint cycles for us.